# disable play multiple sound in the same time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app with 4 tabs.
In all view controllers i have costoum cells with CircularProgressView:

```
@implementation CircularProgressView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
          backColor:(UIColor *)backColor
      progressColor:(UIColor *)progressColor
          lineWidth:(CGFloat)lineWidth
           audioURL:(NSURL *)audioURL {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setUp];
        _backColor = backColor;
        _progressColor = progressColor;
        self.lineWidth = lineWidth;
        _player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
        _audioURL = audioURL;
        _player.delegate = self;
        [_player prepareToPlay];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setUp];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setUp{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
}

- (void)setLineWidth:(CGFloat)lineWidth{
    CAShapeLayer *backgroundLayer = [self createRingLayerWithCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) / 2, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) / 2) radius:CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) / 2 - lineWidth / 2 lineWidth:lineWidth color:self.backColor];
    _lineWidth = lineWidth;
    [self.layer addSublayer:backgroundLayer];
    _progressLayer = [self createRingLayerWithCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) / 2, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame) / 2) radius:CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) / 2 - lineWidth / 2 lineWidth:lineWidth color:self.progressColor];
    _progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0;
    [self.layer addSublayer:_progressLayer];
}

- (void)setAudioURL:(NSURL *)audioURL{
    if (audioURL) {
        [self.player stop];
        self.progress = 0;

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL];
        self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];

        self.duration = self.player.duration;
        [self.player prepareToPlay];
    }
    _audioURL = audioURL;
}

- (CAShapeLayer *)createRingLayerWithCenter:(CGPoint)center radius:(CGFloat)radius lineWidth:(CGFloat)lineWidth color:(UIColor *)color {
    UIBezierPath *smoothedPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(radius, radius) radius:radius startAngle:- M_PI_2 endAngle:(M_PI + M_PI_2) clockwise:YES];
    CAShapeLayer *slice = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    slice.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    slice.frame = CGRectMake(center.x - radius, center.y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
    slice.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    slice.strokeColor = color.CGColor;
    slice.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    slice.lineCap = kCALineJoinBevel;
    slice.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
    slice.path = smoothedPath.CGPath;
    return slice;
}

- (void)setProgress:(float)progress{
    if (progress == 0) {
        self.progressLayer.hidden = YES;
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0;
        });
    }else {
        self.progressLayer.hidden = NO;
        self.progressLayer.strokeEnd = progress;
    }
}

- (void)updateProgressCircle{
    //update progress value
    self.progress = (float) (self.player.currentTime / self.player.duration);
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(CircularProgressViewDelegate)]) {
        [self.delegate updateProgressViewWithPlayer:self.player];
    }
}

- (void)play{
    if (!self.player.playing) {
        if (!self.displayLink) {
            self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateProgressCircle)];
            self.displayLink.frameInterval = 6;
            [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        } else {
            self.displayLink.paused = NO;
        }
        [self.player play];
    }
}

- (void)pause{
    if (self.player.playing) {
        self.displayLink.paused = YES;
        [self.player pause];
    }
}

- (void)stop{
    [self.player stop];
    self.progress = 0;
    self.player.currentTime = 0;
//    [self.displayLink invalidate];
//    self.displayLink = nil;
}

#pragma mark AVAudioPlayerDelegate method
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
    if (flag) {
        [self.displayLink invalidate];
        self.displayLink = nil;
        //restore progress value
        self.progress = 0;
        [self.delegate playerDidFinishPlaying];
    }
}




//calculate angle between start to point
- (CGFloat)angleFromStartToPoint:(CGPoint)point{
    CGFloat angle = [self angleBetweenLinesWithLine1Start:CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) / 2,CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) / 2)
                                                 Line1End:CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) / 2,CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) / 2 - 1)
                                               Line2Start:CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) / 2,CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds) / 2)
                                                 Line2End:point];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame) / 2, CGRectGetHeight(self.frame)), point)) {
        angle = 2 * M_PI - angle;
    }
    return angle;
}

//calculate angle between 2 lines
- (CGFloat)angleBetweenLinesWithLine1Start:(CGPoint)line1Start
                                  Line1End:(CGPoint)line1End
                                Line2Start:(CGPoint)line2Start
                                  Line2End:(CGPoint)line2End{
    CGFloat a = line1End.x - line1Start.x;
    CGFloat b = line1End.y - line1Start.y;
    CGFloat c = line2End.x - line2Start.x;
    CGFloat d = line2End.y - line2Start.y;
    return acos(((a * c) + (b * d)) / ((sqrt(a * a + b * b)) * (sqrt(c * c + d * d))));
}
```

and this lines i add    :

```
cell.circularProgressView.audioURL = url;
[cell.circularProgressView play];
```

everything work , but when i am in another view controller and i want to start a new song, the first is not stoped. Any idea what can i do to play only one song ?

I was trying to make a delegate method :

```
-(void)musicSearchStop{
    selectedIndex = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexButtonSearch inSection:0];
    musicTableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndex];
    [cell.circularProgressView stop];

    CircularProgressView *circular=[[CircularProgressView alloc]init];
    [circular stop];

}
```

but  no results.

Comment: Have you tried calling stop method from another View Controller ( from where you are playing new song)

Comment: yes, but it's not working

Comment: i update my question

Comment: Don't Call method like this  CircularProgressView *circular=[[CircularProgressView alloc]init];

Comment: use  CircularProgressView *circular = (CircularProgressView *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCIndentifier"];

Comment: CircularProgressView is a costoum view , is not a uiview controller

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear { 
  [_player stop]; 
 }
```

Have your tried adding the above code. Also do check if your - (void)viewWillDisappear function is getting called properly.

Comment: Sorry ignore my answer i just missed that its a customview and not a uiviewcontroller.